# EXPO : Export Filesystem to file ,into android folder

Tags: react-native, expo

Good morning ,
Actually i'm working on this recorder .

https://snack.expo.io/@riwu/audio-recorder

How to save the file to device’s folder like download?

Thanks

```
async _stopRecordingAndEnablePlayback() {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true,
        });
        try {
            await this.recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        } catch (error) {
            // Do nothing -- we are already unloaded.
        }
        const info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(this.recording.getURI());

        console.log(`FILE INFO: ${JSON.stringify(info)}`);

        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            allowsRecordingIOS: false,
            interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            playsInSilentLockedModeIOS: true,
            shouldDuckAndroid: true,
            interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
            playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
            staysActiveInBackground: true,
        });
```

Comment: You can use `FileSystem`

Comment: Suppose u mean  : FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync. like  FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(this.recording.getURI(), ?????? ) but dunno what use for content

Comment: Please use Download to save the file.

Comment: Download request a URL. Actually need to store it into Local storage.Am I wrong ?

Comment: You can use `MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localUri)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this. And it Work !!!!

```
    takePictureAndCreateAlbum = async () => {

        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(this.recording.getURI());
        MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Expo', asset)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Album created!');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('err', error);
          });
      }
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: In this scenario isn't asset an object?  Means shouldn't it be: MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Expo', asset.uri)?

Comment: Make sure you ask the permission as well.
await Permissions.askAsync(
    Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL
);

Additionally, it came to my surprise that the above permission can be used for storing audio/video as well. (which was my use case)